# php do code in background

Tags: php, multithreading, execution

I have a code that I want to be executed continually, and not blocking site loading. I need to update a record in the database every second or so. Can anybody help me how to do this?

Here is the code:

```
while(true){
    $hits++;
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "UPDATE u32lb_mt_links SET link_hits='".$hits."' WHERE link_id='".$firma_id."'";
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $db->query();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: @nlsbshtr can you give me an example php code?

Comment: @nlsbshtr Just as an FYI, the minimum resolution of a cron is 1 minute.

Comment: @nlsbshtr No prob, I didn't pick up on it at first either as we've used Quartz scheduler mostly :)

Answer (score 4):

PHP does not support multithreading.

Your best bet would be to look into something like [`pcntl_fork`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php), if you need to spawn the background process when a request comes in.

Otherwise, use a cronjob or execute your script manually using the `php` commandline interpreter.

---

Having said that, I'm not sure what your script is doing. It's intention is just to increment a value by 1 every second instead of every request?

The best thing to use (assuming for a minute that the idea isn't crazy) would be a cronjob that runs every minute, without the `while(true)` and instead just running the task 60 times. Alternatively, run a cron every minute to increase the hit count by 60.

Another alternative is to just create a batch script that loops endlessly (rather than PHP doing it, so you can easily kill the batch file) executing the PHP commandline interpreter until you're done. I still don't see the point, though.

Comment: @JoeWatkins Nice! Would be great for that to become production ready, but there's not a chance I think.

Comment: you know nothing about it ... and yet can form an opinion and affect the choices of others based on what you "know" ...

Comment: I'm not affecting anything, I'll just be very surprised to see it reach production. Regardless, watching PHP developers attempt to use threads will be almost depressing. The missed out call to `->join()` causing their scripts to terminate early and wonder what is going on will be everywhere. I wish you luck in your project, I just don't see it happening.

Comment: "The missed out call to" ... nonsense, again, you have no idea what you are talking about ...

Comment: *sigh*.. My point is that people will be spawning a thread on a class which populates a member, and trying to take the value of the member without waiting for a thread to complete. I'm not discrediting your project in any way, and think that it's a great solution for a specific target, but mainstream production usage will not be widespread, threads are hard enough for most people in real languages.

Comment: 10 years ago object orientated programming was seen as complex, it is more complex today than it was then ... are there any applications left not using object orientation, despite it's apparent difficulty !? Of course not, because our applications and ideas demand it, just like they demand concurrency today; if not because of our ideas then because of our hardware. It already exists, in production, people use curl to run all the way round their stack just to do two things at once. People love to hate on PHP, and even it's users ... shame, it's as much a "real language" as anything else ..

Comment: This discussion is pointless - As I said, I wish you luck, I just don't see it happening. I'm not "hating" on anything, I *am* a PHP user. That does not mean it's a good language.

Comment: Why would you use something you think is bad ... that's a stupid thing to say, only you don't see it because you're so focused on being one of the cool kids calling PHP bad... Co-operative multitasking is already a part of PHP, have a look at how it works and then try to say threads by comparison are complex ... http://nikic.github.com/2012/12/22/Cooperative-multitasking-using-coroutines-in-PHP.html This is a site where you are supposed to help and guide people, if you don't know anything about a subject then you shouldn't form opinions for the sake of the people reading the site.

Comment: Actually, same like the CLR; I'd say Tasks are easier to understand and utilise than Threads directly. You can say what you want, but I'm not "one of the cool kids calling PHP bad", I call it for what it is. Clearly also, by the very virtue of me being here (and my answer here), I am here to help and guide people.. That does not mean that I can't have an opinion.

Comment: The difference is my opinion is based on fact, knowledge in the area. Yours is based on nothing more than fear of the unknown and regurgitated stuff you once read on a blog or whatever. What's more helpful to the observer, to the world at large ? You didn't even bother to verify your opinions by looking at the API in any detail, there is no "direct" manipulation of posix threads, which is why I keep using the word API ... had you looked, you wouldn't be calling it hard, or complex if only you had two minutes to verify what you are saying in public is correct.

Comment: I have looked; and I can assure you have factual knowledge in the area too. I've already stated that your provision is a great addition in the specialised area, and I'm talking from a purely mainstream perspective. I don't believe I ever once insulted your work, yet you continue to insult me. My apologies that I've somehow offended you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, **CRON JOB** is the best way to go. However for some reason your hosting doesn't support adding cron jobs and you don't want to use [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) as **Rudi Visser** stated there is one more option (it is kind of a logic actually).

**Alternative Option;**

Create a page which will update (or do anything you want) record(s). This page should be accessible via URL such as; http://yourwebsite.com/update_records.php

Create a [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) function which you can pass your URL to it and alternatively even timeout parameter. Timeout parameter should be really short.

The logic here is to just execute the script and don't wait for the returned results. Just execute and proceed. This way your page will be able to open fast and you will also get to update your records.

I hope this helps.

P.S.
After sharing thoughts with **didierc**, I realized I should also note possible security suggestions;

- You can add .htaccess rule for deciding who might have access to the page.
- You might want generate a key and add it to database and post this key via query string. Please make it sure that you secure the value from query string. You should also check and confirm the key (or call it token if you will) before proceeding to update records.
- If you don't want it to be executed each time a visitor visits the page then I would suggest you to record when it was executed last time (at least). This way you could check if it needs to be executed.

Depending on how sensitive the records are and what kind of codes you have, you might take extra security measurements.

Comment: if you want to go that way, be very careful of who is accessing that page. Also, iiuc, its call rate will be dependent on your site visit rate.

Comment: Well this could be modified to suit the needs right? Such as adding dynamically created key (and check via DB to confirm) as well as execution time (also checking and confirming via DB) such as if it need to execute & update the records or not.

It was just a suggestion if both other suggestions fails (such as no cron job possibility, PHP is not installed as CGI or many other reasons)

Comment: Yes, but you should include that in your answer, so that OP doesn't end up with a possible security hole. Another option is amending the web server configuration to disallow access from other than localhost. In fact, using as many security checks as possible is the way to go.

Comment: Please note that I am not saying that your answer is wrong, just that it needs to be carefully implemented.

Comment: Oh I didn't understood you wrong **didierc**. Thanks for the heads up. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

make a php script file with whatever you want to do 
and then set a CRON JOB for the same.

Please Refer http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/ to set the CRON JOB

I hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Daemonize the script and turn it into a background process/task: [PEAR System Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon)